# How to generate HTML UI(Firebug show) using .HAR file

Tags: java, javascript, phantomjs, har

Is there any open source utility in which I can input any .HAR files and can get output like firebug shows. I have created .HAR file using Phantom.js, now I want to represent content of .HAR file to end user using .HTML files

Answer (score 1):

You can try the fantastic [har viewer](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-viewer/)  from Jan Odvarko.  It's an online tool to visualize HAR files but you can also host you own version by downloading the [code source](https://github.com/janodvarko/harviewer) on github.